# Using query to change table mapping

Tags: mysql

I have a table mytable( id, key, value). I realize that key is generating a lot of data redundancy since my key is a string. (my keys are really long, but repetititve) How do I build a separate table out that has (key, keyID) and then alternate my table to be mytable( id, keyID, value) and keyTable(keyID, key) ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create `keyTable`
2. Fill keys from `mytable`:

   ```
   INSERT INTO keyTable (`key`) SELECT DISTINCT mytable.key FROM mytable;
   ```
3. add `keyID` column to `mytable`
4. Assign keyIDs:

   ```
   UPDATE mytable SET keyID = (SELECT keyTable.keyID FROM keyTable WHERE keyTable.key = mytable.key);
   ```
5. Remove `key` column from `mytable`

Comment: Good Solution.  Regarding key are keyword so use for differentiation like this `key`.  So check my posting below for more information.

Comment: this is the correct solution, imho.

you have to use DISTINCT when extracting the keys and values from the original table, and you don't need the id column from it.

Answer (score 1):

i just posted my workout for your problem.  Just check this step by step:

```
CREATE TABLE `keytable` (
`keyID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`key` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL,
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL
) ;

insert into `keytable` (`key`,`id`) select `key`,`id` from mytable;

ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE `key` `keyID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ;


update `mytable` set `keyID`= (select `keyID` from keytable where keytable.id=mytable.id)

ALTER TABLE `keytable` DROP `id` ;
```